# Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST

Tags: wso2, resttemplate, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I've the following CURL command which works very fine. But when using through java code. I am using `WSO2 API Manager` version `1.9.1`

```
 curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=test&password=test" -H 
"Authorization: Basic QU01dE04MXFrdzg5ZFNFTjk2Vm0waGgwWnBNYTpzeHcxbko3c2gzdm5NVVlmUDEzVmV1bWtsbTRh, 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://XXXXXX:8243/token
```

I developed the following code using `RestTemplate` API

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://xxxxxxxx:8243/token";

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic QU01dE04MXFrdzg5ZFNFTjk2Vm0waGgwWnBNYTpzeHcxbko3c2gzdm5NVVlmUDEzVmV1bWtsbTRh");
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        headers.add("data", "grant_type=password&username=mahesh&password=mahesh00");

        String json =" {\"data\":\"grant_type=password&username=test&password=test\"}";
        HttpEntity<String> postEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(json, headers);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response =restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,postEntity,String.class);

        System.out.println("\nSTATUS : "+ response.getStatusCode()+" "+response.getStatusCode().getReasonPhrase());
        System.out.println("Response :"+ response.getBody());
    }
}
```

When I execute below, I see the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://192.168.0.102:8243/token":java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:580)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:448)
    at com.java.pushNotifications.Demo.main(Demo.java:25)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1904)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:279)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1446)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:901)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:837)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:81)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:569)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:142)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:91)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:347)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:203)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1428)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: I have the same trouble

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to specify the port in your java code:

```
https://192.168.0.102:/token
```

It should be:

```
https://192.168.0.102:8243/token
```

*You also forgot to hide the IP here as you did with the curl command, but since it is an internal IP there is no reason to bother with it, it means nothing outside of your own LAN. So I am not masking it either.*

Comment: `Connection refused` means that the tcp connection cannot be established. So you got either the IP or the port wrong, or you are not running the curl command from the same env as you run the java code.

Comment: This is not a certificate issue. You will get the same connection refused error if you do a curl call on a random port (that is clearly not open).

Comment: I think we need  to allow connections to SSL sites without certs, then it will work, but how ?

Comment: What? This is now a completely different error. The `connection refused` is fixed then?

Comment: That is cool. Let's close this question then. You can raise a new, describe the issue you get in a clean way, and then somebody can solve that for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I were facing the similar issue-

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   POST request for
>   "http://hostname:port_number/projectname/inbound/message": Connection
>   refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused: connect

So, I am using `application.yml` under `src/main/resources` and I changed the **host value from server ip_address to localhost** for testing with Swagger on my PC,

```
gui:
  protocol: http
  host: localhost
  port: 8280
```

Hope any bit of the information with help someone.