# JUNITS: MockRestServiceServer is Not Running with Maven Build

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit, resttemplate

When I am trying to Run Test Class using Junit everything is working as expected, but when I am building the project I am getting below error, but if I am running the same via JUnits it is working as expected.

Note: I am trying to mock restTemplate which is available in controller class.
Any help will be appreciated.

I have used spring-boot-starter-test dependency only for test env.

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://127.0.0.1:8080/testCnc": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:743)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
    at com.whirlpool.wcloud.acds.requestprocessor.BRP.sendCommand(BRP.java:73)
    at com.whirlpool.wcloud.ja.shapi.processor.CTP.processRequest(CTP.java:26)
    at com.whirlpool.wcloud.ja.shapi.processor.CTP.testDisc(CTP.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:369)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:275)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:239)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:373)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:334)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:407)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
```

Comment: Is your server started when you build your project ? Do you have @SpringBootTest at the top of your JUnit test class ?

Comment: Can you post your code, how are you mocking the RestTemplate ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50699950/10967112

They changed in application.yml under src/main/resources host value from server ip_address to localhost.